# Can you add a new dynamic parameter to an object constructor without changing the object constructor?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype

I'm new to Javascript and learning about objects. I've learned that you can add a new property or method to an object with prototype.

```
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
}

Person.prototype.nationality = "English";
```

Now i'm wondering if it's also possible to add a new property with a new parameter without directly assigning the new property or changing the object constructor.
So, it becomes:

```
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor, nationality) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
  this.nationality = nationality;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by wrapping the original constructor in a new function, like this:

```
const originalPerson = Person;
Person = function(first, last, age, eyecolor, nationality) {
    const instance = new originalPerson(first, last, age, eyecolor);
    instance.nationality = nationality;
    return instance;
};
```

Live Example:

```js
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
}

const originalPerson = Person;
Person = function(first, last, age, eyecolor, nationality) {
    const instance = new originalPerson(first, last, age, eyecolor);
    instance.nationality = nationality;
    return instance;
};

const joe = new Person("Joe", "Bloggs", 42, "brown", "English");
console.log(joe.nationality);
```

You can also do it via inheritance:

```
const originalPerson = Person;
Person = class extends originalPerson {
    constructor(first, last, age, eyecolor, nationality) {
        super(first, last, age, eyecolor);
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }
};
```

Live Example:

```js
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
}

const originalPerson = Person;
Person = class extends originalPerson {
    constructor(first, last, age, eyecolor, nationality) {
        super(first, last, age, eyecolor);
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }
};
const joe = new Person("Joe", "Bloggs", 42, "brown", "English");
console.log(joe.nationality);
```

In both of those cases I've reassigned `Person`, but you don't have to do that, you could just use `ExtendedPerson` or some such:

```
class ExtendedPerson extends Person {
    constructor(first, last, age, eyecolor, nationality) {
        super(first, last, age, eyecolor);
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }
}
```

...and then use `new ExtendedPerson(/*...*/)`.

Live Example:

```js
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
}

class ExtendedPerson extends Person {
    constructor(first, last, age, eyecolor, nationality) {
        super(first, last, age, eyecolor);
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }
}
const joe = new ExtendedPerson("Joe", "Bloggs", 42, "brown", "English");
console.log(joe.nationality);
```